# First element in the array is null or empty in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        String[] sed1 = new String[n];
        String[] sed2 = new String[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            sed1[i] = sc.nextLine();
            sed2[i] = sc.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("OUTPUT:");
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        System.out.print(sed1[j]);
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(sed2[j]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Gives the output after giving the input:

```
3
1 0 2
2 3 4
10 10 10
8 8 8
10 0 10
OUTPUT:
 1 0 2
2 3 4 10 10 10
8 8 8 10 0 10
```

As you can see the first element in the array sed1 is empty, so how do I solve this issue

Comment: What *should* the output be?

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); //<-- here
    String[] sed1 = new String[n];
    String[] sed2 = new String[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        sed1[i] = sc.nextLine();
        sed2[i] = sc.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("OUTPUT:");
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        System.out.print(sed1[j]);
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(sed2[j]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```